# Boot Entry for Loading Encrypted LVM

Tags: arch-linux, lvm, boot-loader, dm-crypt

So, I recently installed Arch Linux (EFI) with the root folder in an encrypted LVM. I am loading the correct modules and hooks on startup, but it's telling me it can not load the encrypted space after I enter the password because of this "unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'"

I am loading both the nls_cp437 and ext4 modules, and the encrypt and lvm2 hooks. This is what the options boot entry looks like. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
options cryptdevice=/dev/VolGroup00/encryptedspace:root root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-encryptedspace quiet rw
```

I assume this is the right layout since /dev/VolGroup00/encryptedspace exists, /dev/mapper/root is where I want to mount it, and /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-encryptedspace is the root.

Comment: `cryptdevice=/dev/sdaX:VG root=/dev/mapper/root`, also you should really use UUID. And normally you have the LVM inside the encrypted partition, unless you want LVM outside maybe. [Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#LVM_on_LUKS)

Comment: So in my case it would be: cryptdevice=/dev/VolGroup00/encryptedspace:VolGroup00-encryptedspace root=/dev/mapper/root ?

Also, I will use UUIDs. I just wanted to try this to make sure it works.

Comment: Since the encrypted space is in a LVM, that's why I use /dev/VolGroup00/encryptedspace, not /dev/sda2 where the LVM is.

Comment: Also, if I go back and encrypt the actual partition instead, would it be cryptdevice=/dev/sda2:VolGroup00 root=/dev/mapper/root

But wait, VolGroup00 is the LVM group. What would VG stand for when a partition is encrypted?

Comment: Ok. In any case `root=` should always point the the actual root filesystem. Btw, that's not the standard way to do full disk encryption and you should take care that swap and home are encrypted too. [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#LUKS_on_LVM)

Comment: Okay. I'll redo it then. Still, what would VG stand for if I encrypt a partition? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If what you want is just "standard" full disk encryption, the 1st wiki link is the way to do it. What you've done is for cases you need a LVM for other purposes. In the "standard" FDE, you need LVM to "partition" the big encrypted actual partition so you can have root, swap, eventually home as separate "partitions" inside the big partition.

Comment: Thanks! If you add an answer stating to use the wiki or something, I'll choose yours as the best answer right after I set up Arch Linux.